# Server folder appears as output url for media, js and skin

Tags: magento-1.9, base-url

Any ideas why Magento 1.9.2.4 sets the beginning of the media, skin and js url's like this /var/www/domain.com/html/ instead of normal http://www.domain.com like it has been set in `unsecure_base_url and secure_base_url`?

I have set up full url for each (js, media and skin) in database so I'm not sure where does that server folder come from.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data media/ var/

More details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336647/styles-not-loading-in-magento-due-to-wrong-url-path-how-to-solve-this

So this was a permission problem.